# AngularJS : `Load more` button in each group of ng-repeat with many groups titles

Tags: angularjs

I want to add `load more` button to the bottom of each group like the image here, and after clicking the button it shows rest of parts of the relevant  group 
[image]

where a,g are groups titles those have `group` property

In the snippet bellow, the code return only one `load more` button, and with no consideration of the `group` property.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('main', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.test = "test";
$scope.filteredModules = [
  {
      "name":"a",
      "group":"a"
    },
    {
      "name":"b",
    },
    { 
      "name":"c",
    },
    { 
      "name":"c",
    },
    { 
      "name":"e",
    },
    { 
      "name":"f",
    },
    { 
      "name":"g",
      "group":"g"
    }
    ,{ 
      "name":"h",
    },
    { 
      "name":"i",
    },
    { 
      "name":"j",
    },
    {
      "name":"k",
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"l",
    }
];
$scope.limit = 4;
$scope.loadMore = function() {         
    var increamented = $scope.limit + 4;
    $scope.limit = increamented > $scope.filteredModules.length ? $scope.filteredModules.length : increamented;
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="main">
<div ng-repeat="node in filteredModules | limitTo:limit track by $index">
    <div ng-if="!node.group">{{node.name}}</div>
    <div ng-if="node.group" style="background-color:red">{{node.name}}  </div>
</div>
<button ng-click="loadMore()">Load more</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: mark @MohitTanwani answer right if it serves your purpose.

Comment: That's right answer, but I have to change data structure.. I'll  convert my data to how you make it, and i'll mark your answer as right.  @MohitTanwani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this snippet

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('main', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.filteredModules = { 
    "groups":
        [
            {
              "title": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
              "childs": ["child-1", "child-2", "child-3", "child-4", "child-5", "child-6","child-7", "child-8", "child-9"],
              "limit": "3"
            },
            {
              "title": "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados",
              "childs": ["child-1", "child-2", "child-3", "child-4", "child-5", "child-6"],
              "limit": "4"
            },
            {
              "title": "Antonio Moreno Taquería",
              "childs": ["child-1", "child-2", "child-3", "child-4", "child-5", "child-6"],
              "limit": "3"
            }
        ]
    };

$scope.loadMore = function(index) {         
     $scope.filteredModules.groups[index].limit = parseInt($scope.filteredModules.groups[index].limit) + 3;
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="main">
<div ng-repeat="node in filteredModules.groups track by $index">
    <div ng-if="node.title" style="background-color:red">{{node.title}}
      
    </div>
      <div ng-repeat="child in node.childs | limitTo: node.limit">
        {{child}}
      </div>
      <br/>
      <button ng-click="loadMore($index)" ng-hide="node.limit >= node.childs.length">Load more</button>
<br/><br/>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have  ideas about hiding `load more` button if there are no more data to load? thanks @MohitTanwani

Comment: @HalaElBarchah: I've edited my code, please check now.

Comment: Thank you again, you're great @MohitTanwani