# How to implement show more button in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement show more functionality. I have to show 6 rows and on click of show more button should display next rows using html table. The data is coming in json format.How can i do this?
     //this displays only first 6 rows how can i display it through showMore button

Comment: Hi you can check this answer for your requirement.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38995067/1506955

Comment: if you are using `ng-repeat="x in array"`, extend it with `| limitTo:num` and control `$scope.num` manually with some button. If you are loading it dynamically, you might need to look into `infinite-scroll` modules